# Не работает "импорт" с jsfiddle.net

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Доброго времени суток! Требуется помощь! 
В общем, в песочнице все работает исправно. 
http://jsfiddle.net/zawex/bmnUG/5/

> (задача - по клику на картинку вывод блока, а по клику в любое кроме блока место, его закрытие)

Однако когда пытаюсь реализовать на практике (уже пытался просто в хтмл чистом, локально) событие при клике на изображение не работает. 
Подключаю только jquery-1.9.1 - последний.

Упорно не понимаю что не так. И почему это "что", не так.
Заранее `спасибо`.

**upd.** код который вставляю

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />         
        <title>vsd</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mysite.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
            *** /*скрипт аналогично Jsfiddle */ 
        </script> 
        /*хтмл код*/ 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, что при копипасте с Jsfiddle бывает проблема со знаками переноса строки, и в консоль вываливается ошибка.
Попробуйте переписать вручную оттуда, или заменить переносы строк на свои.
Лучший способ проверить - запустите весь код одной строкой.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло(

Answer (score 1):

Там выставлено выполнение скриптов on load, т. е. после загрузки документа. Если ты копируешь просто код и не добавляешь при этом подписку на событие `load`, то твой код не эквивалентен коду в фиддле.

Answer (score 0):

В твоем случае, когда выполняется код

```
var btn = $('#cartsho'),
    ovl = $('.overlay');
```

эти элементы еще не добавлены в DOM, и соответственно - селекторы вернут 0 элементов. Для исправления - можно перенести объявление этого скрипта после Html

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />         
        <title>vsd</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mysite.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        /*хтмл код*/ 
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
           //когда выполняется это код - уже все html элементы доступны
            *** /*скрипт аналогично Jsfiddle */ 
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```